# Django+Apache+ModWSGI Hangs Indefinitely

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I have a Django 1.11 site served from Apache 2.4.18 + ModWSGI on Ubuntu 16 and it hangs indefinitely. What's odd is that if I stop Apache, only then does it return the request, which renders the page perfectly, implying Django is correctly returning the request, but something's preventing Apache from sending out the data.

My Apache site.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.mysite.com
    ServerAlias www.mysite.com
    ServerAdmin sysadmin@mysite.com
    DocumentRoot /usr/local/mysite

    AllowEncodedSlashes On

    Alias /media/ /usr/local/mysite/media/
    Alias /static/ /usr/local/mysite/static/

    <Directory /usr/local/mysite>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        # New directive needed in Apache 2.4.3.
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>

    LogLevel debug
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/mysite-error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/mysite-access.log combined

    # Stop GIL deadlocks from crashing Python/Modwsgi due to Python C-extensions?
    # Without this, you may get a "Premature end of script" error.
    # https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ApplicationIssues#Python_Simplified_GIL_State_API
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}

    WSGIDaemonProcess www.mysite.com python-path=/usr/local/mysite/.env/lib/python2.7/site-packages processes=1  display-name=%{GROUP} user=www-data group=www-data
    WSGIProcessGroup www.mysite.com
    WSGIScriptAlias / /usr/local/mysite/wsgi/mysite.wsgi

    <Directory /usr/local/mysite/wsgi>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

My Django wsgi:

```
import os
import time
import traceback
import signal
import sys

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'mysite.settings.settings'
os.environ['CELERY_LOADER'] = 'django'

sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__)), '../src'))
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__)), '../src/mysite'))

try:
    application = get_wsgi_application()
    print 'WSGI without exception'
except Exception:
    print 'handling WSGI exception'
    # Error loading applications
    if 'mod_wsgi' in sys.modules:
        traceback.print_exc()
        os.kill(os.getpid(), signal.SIGINT)
        time.sleep(2.5)
```

The only thing of interest in my Apache logs are a few lines like:

```
[Fri Oct 27 02:37:08.079977 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 14053:tid 139644805011200] [client 10.182.122.159:45695] Timeout when reading response headers from daemon process 'www.mysite.com': /usr/local/mysite/wsgi/mysite.wsgi
```

Clearly, it seems like something's not getting the right signal, causing it to wait until a timeout occurs, but I can't figure out what the cause is. I've tried refactoring my Apache config, and disabling parts of my Django app that might be timing out, but nothing's worked. How do I diagnose this?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely your requests are blocking and never returning. Nothing to do with signals, or Apache's own use of signals at least. The shutdown signal may be interrupting some system call your request is blocked on.

Add to `WSGIDaemonProcess` directive the option:

```
request-timeout=60
```

and monitor the logs to see if mod_wsgi daemon process get restarted due to request timeouts.

Because you are using single process with default of 15 threads, because of how request timeouts are applied as an average across all request handlers, if only a single request handler is blocking indefinitely, it will take up to 15 minutes for forced restart of process. If multiple requests are blocking, then will be quicker than that.

I am presuming here that 60 seconds is more than your expect you requests to run for. Set it lower if you requests should always be handled much quicker than that.

You also don't need that `try/except/kill` stuff in your WSGI script file. Instead of that add to `WSGIDaemonProcess` the option:

```
startup-timeout=15
```

Comment: The try/except/kill stuff is necessary, otherwise ModWSGI obscures Python exceptions from the logs. I learned that tip from another SO answer to the question, "Why can't I see Django exceptions in my Apache logs?"

Comment: Also, `startup-timeout` doesn't appear to be a valid Apache option. With that, Apache refuses to load my config.

Comment: Why do you suggest using `request-timeout=60`? I already know my requests are timing out, as evidenced by the log entry I posted. I'm trying to find the cause of the timeout.

Comment: With that `request-timeout` directive, I now see some log entries like `Truncated or oversized response headers received from daemon process mysite`. Googling that shows it could be caused by any number of problems.

Comment: You will see those messages if the mod_wsgi daemon processes are being forcibly restarted due to request timeouts. You should see a bunch of other messages as well so make sure checking the logs. Check the main Apache log as well if need be, but I think the messages should be in the virtual host log.

Comment: The reason ``startup-timeout`` isn't working is because your mod_wsgi is very old. The latest version is 4.5.20, so you are very far behind.

Comment: The messages also require at least ``LogLevel info``, so if you put that back to ``warn`` from ``debug``, you will not see them.

Comment: If you use a new enough mod_wsgi version, from memory, when a request timeout does occur, mod_wsgi should try and log information on where the request was stuck, helping you to isolate the issue. So see if you can upgrade mod_wsgi to the latest version.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem, but even after a shorter timeout (30), there is no error in the debug log, apart from some harmless template variable ones. The full HTML is loaded in the expected time, but the request does not complete until the server timeout is hit.